# Is it compulsory to use a controller for ng-include

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to create multiple document of a template.

I have a Navigation which i want to load from different page. Here is what i do.

```
<ons-template id="menu.html">
    <ons-page modifier="menu-page" ng-include="menuPage.html">
      //HTML tags which will be called from menuPage.html
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>
```

But it seems like ng-include is not working here. Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: doesn't make sense that you have same id as include path but not on a script tag per angular docs. Thus it's hard to tell what you are expecting ng-include to do ... make ajax request or use in page template?

Comment: Yes actually there was some problem. Now i corrected it. Still no idea.

Comment: didn't answer second part. If it's intended to load file inspect the actual request in dev tools network tab for clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add single quotes to `ng-include`:

```
<ons-page modifier="menu-page" ng-include="'menu.html'"></ons-template>
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:////www/menuPage.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9658sendReq @ angular.js:9462$get.serverRequest angular.js:25579trigger @ angular.js:2742eventHandler @ angular.js:3013
angular.js:11358 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:////www/menuPage.html'.
    at Error (native)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Volumes/Work%20Data/Development/Come%20to%20woodstock%20Icons/ComeToWoodstockIphone/Come%20To%20Woodstock/www/menuPage.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: These errors are regarding cross origin requests. If you're running local development server, you should not get these errors.

Comment: No i am using this to create a PhoneGap app.

Comment: Well i'm not sure about that without knowing more about your setup. This answers you're original question regarding `ng-include` not working.